# Rewrite mysub.mydomain.com/uploads/* to mysub.mydomain/mysub/uploads/*

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am having trouble with RewriteCond and RewriteRule.  I want to rewrite a url of the form:

http://mysub.mydomain.com/uploads/image.png

to

http://mysub.mydomain.com/mysub/uploads/image.png

so that my AliasMatch:

```
AliasMatch "^/(.+)/uploads/(.*)$" "/var/www/html/test/client_files/$1/uploads/$2"
```

will direct the request to the right resource.

This is what I have so far:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}                   ^[^.]+\.mydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}                 ^uploads/(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.+)                          %{HTTP_HOST}$1 [C]
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)\.mydomain\.com(.*)    %{HTTP_HOST}$1/$2 [L]
```

However it does not work.  I get message saying the requested url was not found.  Can anyone tell me how to correct the issue(s) with the rewriting that I am doing?

UPDATE #1
I am using this in a virtual host in my httpd.conf file.  I got the following to work based on @user2493235 answer, however my AliasMatch is not being applied after the rewrite.  It just adds the document root to the rewritten uri.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}        ^([^.]+)\.mydomain\.com$
RewriteRule ^(\/uploads\/.*)$     /%1$1
```

I have tried various versions of the AliasMatch and even changed it to an Alias.  It does not seem to process the AliasMatch after the rewrite.

Comment: I updated my answer to address your problem in the UPDATE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^(/uploads/.+)$ /%1$1 [PT]
```

Comment: I am using a virtual host in my httpd.conf file.  I got the following to work based on your answer, however my AliasMatch is not being applied after the rewrite.  It just adds the document root to the rewritten uri.

Comment: I am using a virtual host in my httpd.conf file.  I got the following to work based on your answer, however my AliasMatch is not being applied after the rewrite.  It just adds the document root to the rewritten uri.    'code' RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}        ^([^.]+)\.mydomain\.com$
RewriteRule ^(\/uploads\/.*)$     /%1$1 'code'

Comment: Sorry about that. I updated the answer, adding the `[PT]` flag to the `RewriteRule` which should hopefully fix it. I also find it doesn't actually matter if the `AliasMatch` is before or after the rewrites in your config so I removed that info from my answer. Let me know if that fixes it.

Comment: I removed the `.htaccess` part of my answer as you don't need it and it's not going to get tested.

Comment: Yes, adding the [PT] made it work.  What does the PT do?  I know it stands for Pass Through, but I am not clear on how it works.  Do I need to be concerned about security?

Comment: Glad it worked. No security concern. It just tells the system that the rewritten URL should be processed by `Alias` and friends rather than being treated as a file path. [Details here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_pt). Please accept my answer and an upvote would be much appreciated too.